# Update local project with lastly updated/edited git repo

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, pull

I've lastly done some changes in my Project and `git push`ed it into the GitHub server. But now, I've done some changes in my local desktop projects and it is showing some error. I want to update that lastly `pushed` data into my local desktop but `git pull` isn't doing anything except printing `Already upto date`. This is so tedious and frustating. How to update the lastly push data to my LOCAL desktop.

Need help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

```
git stash
git pull
```

Read here first! [source](https://www.datree.io/resources/git-force-pull)

Comment: It didn't worked. Just popped the same message: `Already up to date.`

Comment: can you update your post with that error massage you got after your changes?

Comment: Nope. It's did nothing.